# Fetching data from Web page displayed in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

Because of some weird requirements, I have to fetch a GUID from http://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx using a UIWebView.

I have added a UIWebView in my application and can open the site in it. However, I need to copy the generated GUID from the web page into a local database. Is there any way I can access the HTML document currently loaded in the UIWebView so that I may copy the GUID from the page?

Feel free to ask for clarifications if any of the requirements are not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish - get a GUID somehow? There are easier ways to do this in most programming languages...

Comment: act i did not want to get GUID any more.... this is just one example how to get any data from web page in UIWebView???   Basically i opened one site in webview and the site give me some info which is not display on web page . when i clicked on "SAVE" button in web page , that info should stored in my application....

Comment: Thanks for reply,

Basically i dont want GUID number at all . This is just one example 
The real problem i am fetching is , If i load any web page in my webview and i want to store some info from that page.

suppose , i open one site xyz.com , i logged in and do some task , site gives me the "TASK ID" by some way on web page .  Now i want to store that "TASK ID" in local database of my application.( sqlite)  so i can populate list of "TASK ID" (UItableView)   user has already done. 

Note: 
This is not client-server model. I just want to fetch data from web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIWebView's instance method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method.
You just have to pass the Javascript code as argument.

The return of the function will be the NSString object. Save it and use it.